# eclipse tomcat servlet the requested resource is not available

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I am following a video on Youtube to create a simple HelloWorld servlet web dynamic project in eclipse, but it does not work as excepted. 
Here is my project:
[image]

[image]

The server is tomcat7, the setting is 
[image]
All of these are followed in a tutorial, however, when I run the servlet it I get this:[image] and it throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException.
[image]
Someone please help...

Comment: did you add server-api.jar into your build/class path?

Comment: you mean servlet-api.jar?yes it is added under Apache tomcat

Comment: Do not add that yourself. You should only be getting the APIs to compile against from Tomcat itself. Are you able to change the Server Location to one that doesn't require modifying the Tomcat installation? What about if the project is named with something other than a number?

Comment: It is added automatically which is under Libraries Apache Tomcat 7.0. I tried the project with different names and content root, but none of them worked. What do you mean by change server location which doesnt require modifying the Tomcat installation?  Thank you

Comment: what is the exact package of your HelloWorld.java class is in? and what is the name of your jsp file? this should be a web.xml mapping issue.

Comment: the package is "lee" which is shown in the first package. The jsp is a dummy page called "NewFile.jsp" which contains a form with the action pointed to the servlet                                                                        <form action="helloWorld" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>

Comment: will you please add servlet-api.jar manually and check. Because your problem seems somewhere somehow that jar is missing

Comment: I tried to clean and build the project and it worked after. Thanks for your help.